# CORS Vue and OctoberCMS

Tags: vue.js, cors, octobercms

**Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

I'm building an application with Vue (VueX, vue-router, ...) and OctoberCMS. I create virtual domain for API and APP in local via MAMP. I had config all CORS via plugin 'rluders-cors' in OctoberCMS.

```
Route::group(
    [
        'prefix' => 'api/v1',
        'middleware' => ['api','jwt.auth','\Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors'],
    ],
    function () {
         // Routes here
    }
);
```

When I deployed into VPS (Centos 6), I have above response from browser. I had added header in .htaccess file of API. And when I open API dirrectly via browser (turn of jwt.auth middleware), I get all header which set in .htaccess file. But in App, don't work.

I tried to use primary domain for App (abc.example) to call the API from my virtual domain in local (local.local), it still worked. But I tried local App to call the primary API in VPS, it didn't work.

Please help me! Thanks.

Comment: It is the preflight OPTIONS request that is failing. Accessing the API directly from the browser won't trigger CORS, so no preflight will be sent. You should be able to see the preflight OPTIONS request in the Network tab of your browser's developer tools when you try to make the request from within your application (if not, try a different browser). Inspect the response headers in the developer tools to check what's coming back. The error message suggests that `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is missing from that request.

Comment: Provisional headers are shown. I don't have any OPTIONS request in both Chrome and Safari browsers

Answer (score 0):

So my solution for routes was to look for a preflight response. So in the request data if it is empty I am sending the preflight response (I think any string would do). Then here comes a request that is not empty. This was the easiest work around that I have found. You still have to allow access control domain. I typically set it to all and always have a token system to authenticate methods other than GET.

```
Route::match(['POST', 'OPTIONS'],'api/update-todo', function(Request $req) {
$data = $req->input();
if (!empty($data)) {
    Todo::where('id', $data['id'])
        ->update([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'description' => $data['description'],
        'status' => $data['status'] 
    ]);
    return response()->json([
        'Success' => $data,
    ]);
} else {
    return response()->json([
      'Success' => $req,
    ]);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it worked with :

```js
Route::options('/{any}', function() {
   $headers = [
        //'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'=> 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'=> 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin, Authorization'
   ];
   return \Response::make('You are connected to the API', 200, $headers);
})->where('any', '.*');
```